# How to judge if server support partial content?

Tags: python, http-headers, python-requests

I am working on my own multi-threaded web downloader. Before start, I had searched the same question but the articles told me if the server support partial content, they can Accept a request header `Range: bytes=a-b` and return `206` respond code. Based on this rule, here is my code.

```
# Occur HEAD request and get more information
def _get_url_header(self):
    interface.info_out('HEAD_REQUEST')
    headers = {
        'Range': 'bytes=0-1'
    }
    response = requests.head(self.url, stream = True, headers = headers)
    print(response.status_code)
    # This if statement need modify!!!
    if response.status_code == 206:
        self.partital_content = True
        interface.info_out('PARTITAL_SUPPORT')
    elif response.status_code // 100 == 4:
        interface.info_out('CONNECTION_ERROR', response.status_code)
    elif response.status_code // 100 == 2:
        self.partital_content = False
        interface.info_out('PARTITAL_NOT_SUPPORT')
```

But when I test my code, I found by accident that although I got `200` code, the server still accept my `Range` headers, in other words, the server still support partial content transmission!
So what goes wrong? How do I say whether a server support partial content?

Comment: Accepting (or at least *not rejecting*) the `Range` header doesn't necessarily mean they support partial content transmission. If you don't get a 206 the server doesn't support it, and is likely just ignoring headers it can't deal with.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But when I test my code, the md5sum of output file using multithread from 200 respond is same as single thread. It is really a weird thing, can it be explained?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I found that check whether content-range is in response headers is a good idea.